# Save video file to device in Flutter

Tags: ios, file, video, flutter, save

I can not save video file to iOS(to be visible in Photos app).
I have tried some plugins but they only save IMAGE(not video) to Photos. 
I have used:

```
image_picker_saver: 0.3.0
```

It works fine for saving images(iOS), and rotates image for 90 degrees on Android.

For recording, I'm using image_picker: ^0.6.0+10

Any ideas?
Thanks.

Edit:

In the meantime, we have developed a plugin which supports saving both images and videos to gallery(android)/photos(ios), from Camera or url.

https://pub.dev/packages/gallery_saver

it has methods saveImage and saveVideo that take path or url(String).

Comment: You mean ask how to save(or download) a remote video file to device?

Comment: Nope. I want to save video that I have captured. I'm able to record it, but I can not save it to device(photos in iOS).

Comment: Could you please mention what library you are making use of to do the recording? Usually it will have the supporting functions.

Comment: image_picker: ^0.6.0+10

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/gallery_saver

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/gallery_saver

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/gallery_saver

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the mentioned [gallery_saver](https://pub.dev/packages/gallery_saver) gallery_saver. There is another existing package that would do the trick, [image_gallery_saver](https://pub.dev/packages/image_gallery_saver). Check [this blog](https://retroportalstudio.medium.com/saving-files-to-application-folder-and-gallery-in-flutter-e9be2ebee92a) for the complete guide on how to save files to your own Flutter App Folder in Internal Phone Storage on Android and to the Photos Library on iOS Device. See also the package [file_saver](https://pub.dev/packages/file_saver), which is another pretty decent plugin for saving files with formats like `PDF`, `MP3`, `MP4`, etc.